# Configure startup order of websphere application withing EAR

Tags: websphere

Is it possible to define startup order of the WebSphere enterprise application within EAR (some of descriptor/binding files, META-INF or anywhere else)?

The procedure [described in IBM InfoCenter](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/trun_app_startup.html) requires using AdminConsole, but I would prefer to set fixed order in the EAR to assert that our 2 EAR's will start in fixed order (one is requiring the other to start before).

Unfortunatelly, I haven't found in Internet any way for setting startup order other then AdminConsole/wsadmin. I don't want to go into AdminConsole each time I redeploy the EAR.

Answer (score 0):

Not true with Websphere version 6 of the application.xml, there is a setting for true which will boot up the war's in the order they are defined.

Answer (score 0):

Using Websphere specific configuration xml, `<EAR>/src/main/application/META-INF/ibmconfig/cells/defaultCell/applications/defaultApp/deployments/defaultApp/deployment.xml`, we could set startup order.

Example: `startingWeight="100"`

```
    <appdeployment:Deployment xmi:version="2.0" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/XMI" xmlns:appdeployment="http://www.ibm.com/websphere/appserver/schemas/5.0/appdeployment.xmi" xmi:id="Deployment_1343411066534">
    <deployedObject xmi:type="appdeployment:ApplicationDeployment" xmi:id="ApplicationDeployment_1343411066534" startingWeight="100">
```